# Spark SQL Transformation returns no data (Structured Streaming)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Kafka stream through which I am getting JSON based IoT device logs.I'm using pyspark to process the stream to analyze and create a transformed output.

My device json looks like this:

```
{"messageid":"1209a714-811d-4ad6-82b7-5797511d159f",
"mdsversion":"1.0",
"timestamp":"2020-01-20 19:04:32 +0530",
"sensor_id":"CAM_009",
"location":"General Assembly Area",
"detection_class":"10"}

{"messageid":"4d119126-2d12-412c-99c2-c159381bee5c",
"mdsversion":"1.0",
"timestamp":"2020-01-20 19:04:32 +0530",
"sensor_id":"CAM_009",
"location":"General Assembly Area",
"detection_class":"10"}
```

I'm trying to transform the logs in a way that it returns me unique count of each device based on the timestamp and sensor id. The result JSON would look like this:

```
{
"sensor_id":"CAM_009",
"timestamp":"2020-01-20 19:04:32 +0530",
"location":"General Assembly Area",
count:2
}
```

Full code that I'm trying - pyspark-kafka.py

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('analytics').getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('ERROR')
brokers='kafka-mybroker-url-host:9092'
readTopic = 'DetectionEntry'
outTopic = 'DetectionResults'

df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",brokers).option("subscribe",readTopic).load()

transaction_detail_df1 = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)", "timestamp")
alert_schema = StructType() \
    .add("message_id", StringType()) \
    .add("mdsversion", StringType()) \
    .add("timestamp", StringType()) \
    .add("sensor_id", StringType()) \
    .add("location", StringType()) \
    .add("detection_class", StringType()) \

transaction_detail_df2 = transaction_detail_df1\
        .select(from_json(col("value"), alert_schema).alias("alerts"))

transaction_detail_df3 = transaction_detail_df2.select("alerts.*")
transaction_detail_df3 = transaction_detail_df3.withColumn("timestamp",to_timestamp(col("timestamp"),"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss SSSS")).withWatermark("timestamp", "500 milliseconds")

tempView = transaction_detail_df3.createOrReplaceTempView("alertsview")
results = spark.sql("select sensor_id, timestamp, location, count(*) as count from alertsview group by sensor_id, timestamp, location")
results.printSchema()

results_kakfa_output = results
results_kakfa_output.writeStream \
    .format("console") \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .trigger(processingTime='3 seconds') \
    .start().awaitTermination()
```

When I run this code, I get the following output. The overall objective is to process the entire device logs on an interval of 3 seconds and find unique counts for each timestamp entry for a device within the interval period. I have tried the SQL query on a MySQL database with same schema and it works fine. However, I'm getting no results here in the output to process further. I'm unable to figure out what am I missing here.

[image]

Comment: are you sure there are new messages coming to the kafka topic while the spark job is running. by default spark will not read the old messages in a kafka topic

Comment: yes. i could see the messages in spark before transformation